# Terminology: Group extensions, the derived subgroup, abelianization

Tags: group-theory, terminology

Let $P_1$ and $P_2$ be group properties (for example, "solvable" or "finitely generated").

Let $G$ be a group. Assume that the derived subgroup $[G,G]$ has property $P_1$ and the abelianization $G/[G,G]$ has property $P_2$.

Then, in group extension terminology, $G$ is "$P_1$ by $P_2$".
However, "$P_1$ by $P_2$" only means that there is *some* normal subgroup $H$ of $G$ with property $P_1$, such that $G/H$ has property $P_2$. Is there a concise accepted way to express the more specific fact that in this extension $H=[G,G]$?

Comment: Isn't it implicit in the order that you state the properties? That is, $P_1$ by $P_2$ is distinct from $P_2$ by $P_1$.

Comment: @Mr. Chip: Yes, the order matters, but that's not what I tried to ask. When we say "$P_1$ by  $P_2$", it means that there is *some* normal subgroup $H$ of $G$ with property $P_1$, such that $G/H$ has property $P_2$. It doesn't say that $H$ is the specific normal subgroup $[G,G]$.

Comment: Ah, I see. I suggest you edit your question to that effect, since currently it seems trivial.

Comment: @Mr.Chip: Thanks for pointing this out. I edited the question accordingly.